# c# OpenFileDialogue Initial directory using relative path

Tags: c#

How can I set the initial directory to be where my test data exists?

```
var relPath = System.IO.Path.Combine( Application.StartupPath, "../../" )

dlg.Title = "Open a Credit Card List";
dlg.InitialDirectory = relPath ;
```

The default directory it opens up to is where the .exe exists: Project2\Project2\bin\Debug

I want it to open up by default in the Project2 folder where my test data exists. But it does not allow me to move up a parent directory. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`Directory.GetParent(string path)`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent)

```
string relPath = Directory.GetParent(Application.StartupPath).Parent.FullName;
```

Or using `DirectoryInfo`

```
DirectoryInfo drinfo =new DirectoryInfo(path);

DirectoryInfo twoLevelsUp =drinfo.Parent.Parent;
dlg.InitialDirectory = twoLevelsUp.FullName;;
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert your relative path to an absolute path you can use `Path.GetFullPath()`

```
var relPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"\..\..");
relPath = Path.GetFullPath(relPath);
dlg.InitialDirectory = relPath;
```

Alternatively if you wish to change the working directory to your test data:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(relPath);
```

More information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory.aspx

Comment: You are going to want to either declare that string `@`, use `\\ ` or switch the direction of those slashes or else you will get a compiler error.

Comment: oops, that's what you get for typing an answer in a hurry. Fixed.